# Simple rail & hooks solution to attach a bin to the inside of a cupboard

Tags: cabinets, trash-can

I want to attach our bin (trash can, for the US readers), which is basically a plastic rectangle, to the inside of the door of one of the cupboards in our kitchen.  The bin will need to be removed for cleaning, so I can't attach it directly - it needs to hang on something.

So, I'll permanently attach some hooks to the side of the bin, and permanently attach something for these hooks to hook **onto**, on the inside of the cupboard door, such as a rail or some brackets or something similar (or perhaps vice versa).

I'd like the hooks to be thin, so as to not have (or minimise) the gap between the door and the bin, but still strong so that they don't bend over time, so probably steel.

I'd have thought that these hooks and brackets would be easy to source but I'm having trouble finding them on DIY stores' websites, which are returning coathooks and the like.

Is there a name for what i'm looking for, which would help me find it?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all plastic trash bins have a turned over lip around the top. Why not make a French cleat slightly narrower than the width of the bin and hang the bin by its lip on the cleat?

[image: trash hanger]

A French cleat is a long narrow board whose front edge is higher than its back edge. A mating board with the reverse configuration is then hung on it. In this case, the bin lip is the mating piece.

You could use a small rotating clip, such as a plastic mirror clip, to keep the bin from bouncing off the cleat. Just don't tighten the retaining screw too much.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bib.   Nice diagram too, cheers :)  I think it does have a lip but i don't know if it's big enough to hang the bin off - i'll investigate tonight.

Comment: @MaxWilliams : if it doesn't, and you have some heavy wire (14 ga or better) or strapping, you might be able to make something to go under the bin's edge to spread the weight better.  You could also bend it on one side to add protrusions that you could use to attach it to other types of hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider typical closet shelf brackets. They'll be easy to find and rigid enough for your needs. You can install them reversed (vertically) if needed to arrive at less depth.

[image] [image]

Be aware that your cabinet door will need to be substantially wider than the bin to clear the arc when opening and closing.

Comment: What about inverting them and attaching to a board a bit wider than the bin. Then the angle braces serve as lateral limiters.

Comment: Sure, but then you have a board getting dirty and wet. It's a trash can. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @isherwood, but i'm not sure what you intend for the shelf brackets - how would the bin attach to them?  Are you intending that the bin sits on them?  cheers

Comment: Yes, I pictured the bin simply hanging between.